# How to make SPFx extension triggered when new file uploaded to Sharepoint libraty?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, react

I'm making a SPFx extension. I want it to trigger each time when new file uploaded in my Sharepoint library.
Could someone assist me with achieving this functionality?

Comment: Are you creating a SPFx ListView command set? I don't think you can trigger the SPFx extension on new file uploads. You have to select the file and click button from list command bar to execute SPFx extension code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I think You may use "Subscribe to list notification".
Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/subscribe-to-list-notifications